# Local Notification with no display, only sound/vibrate

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an app that sends out local notifications as a timer runs out.  I have that part all setup.  There is a notification for the thirty second mark, then from ten to one.  When the ten to one go off, all the notifications get jumbled together and it gets kinda messed up.  Now I have only the ten, five and one go off.  This makes it much cleaner.  I would like to have a vibrate and sound go off for the 9-6 and 4-2, but have no view show up.  I know apple is very strict on this sort of stuff, but is there a way that I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the current setup of notifications at 10, 5, 1, and use a custom, longer looping sound for 10 and 5. I'm not sure if there's anything you can do to make the vibration repeat as well.